# Analytical solution nonlinear partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Do you know how I can solve nonlinear PDEs analytically i.e does the perturbation method work?

e.g $$a^2u_{tt} - u_{xx}+ f(u)=0$$ where $f$ is nonlinear in $u$, with boundary condition. what the general approach that I can use for this problem?